# Save results of each for loop as new data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, bioinformatics

This is my first post ever so apologies up front for any inconvienance.

I'm trying to extract RNAseq data from cBioPortal with their function getProfileData(). I want to call this function on each of elements of my list with parameters generated from element of this list. I included a library, example cancers and example genes that can be called by this function.

```
library(cgdsr)
mycgds = CGDS("http://www.cbioportal.org/")

cancers1 = c("cesc_tcga", "ov_tcga", "ucs_tcga", "ucec_tcga")
genes = c("PTCH1", "PTCH2")

mRNAseqExtractor <- function(){   
  for(i in cancers1){
    i_RNAseq <- paste(i, "_rna_seq_v2_mrna", sep="")        
    i_all <- paste(i, "_all", sep="")        
    getProfileData(mycgds, genes, i_RNAseq, i_all)   } }

mRNAseqExtractor()
```

Basically, i want each iteration of this loop to save output of this getProfileData(mycgds, hedgehog_genes, i_RNAseq, i_all)  to a new data frame.

PS.
I was looking for similar post but couldn't find any that generate new global data frames in each iteration.

Comment: Write a function `f(cancer)` to extract the profile data for a single datapoint, and then use `lapply` to generate a list of dataframes (or whatever the output of `getProfiledata` is).  `Output <- lapply(cancers1,f)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lapply to return a list of dataframes.

```
profiles <- lapply(cancers1, function(i) {
    i_RNAseq <- paste(i, "_rna_seq_v2_mrna", sep="")        
    i_all <- paste(i, "_all", sep="")        
    getProfileData(mycgds, genes, i_RNAseq, i_all)
})
```

You can then access the individual data frames like this:

```
# access first data frame
print(profiles[[1]])
```